# Retrieve agents to buffer when needed from storage with AGV

Tags: anylogic

All the agents coming from the source are moved to Storage and are to be stayed there without retrieving, only when the buffer (queue) is less then its capacity i.e.,3 then an AGV should take the agent from store and pass it to the buffer.

Here the station does some continuous process, once a process is finished the other agent should be ready to process, hence the buffer has to be filled when ever it gets empty

[Process trying to achive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVLfO.png)

[Logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZaRU.png)

I have created an event with a function that checks every if the buffer is full or not

Unfortunately, this is working

[Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK9zP.png)

please help me with this

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I best do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Welcome again, happy to help

Comment: Understood, will post in linkedin from now

Comment: Use both places: LinkedIn for open-ended "how do I do X?" questions, SOF for specific technical problems ("how can I fix this error Y?"). Both are great for their specific use cases